# C# WebSocket, перехват события (DonationAlerts)

Tags: c#, сокет, события

Моя цель - получить событие "донат" от стороннего ресурса (DonationAlerts) для дальнейшей обработки сообщения. Связывался с поддержкой по этому поводу, как это можно сделать и получил такой ответ:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Немного погуглил про сокеты на C#, написал следующее

```
        socket = new Client("socket.donationalerts.ru:80");
        RequestDA requestDA = new RequestDA(){ Token = "FvMFkwxi.....B4z5b", Type = "minor" };
        socket.Emit("add-user", requestDA);
        socket.On("donation", (data) =>
        {
            // функция, обрабатывающая донат
            SendMessage("Произошло чудо! Мы перехватили донат!");
        });
        socket.Connect();
```

Однако реакция, написанная в `socket.On()` никогда не срабатывает. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Откуда у тебя вообще этот класс `Client`? тонну документации перерыл что бы понять что у тебя может быть не так, а я даже класса найти не могу

Comment: @ZecosMAX `using SocketIOClient;`